# Building a static version of Python - modules statically available

Tags: python, configuration, compilation, cython, portability

We are trying to build a portable version of Python that can run on any system (with any or no python installed) in order to run our application there.

All is fine except that we want to have some modules available statically that should be uncommented at:

```
/Modules/Setup
```

The problem is that we do not want to alter the Setup file and need to find some other way to uncomment the modules needed to be included statically.

Is it possible to somehow do it via the ./configure script or setup.py? (i.e. supply the name of the modules and build them statically)

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you on? On windows there is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: The build envirnoment is on CentOS 5.11. We are creating a python interpreter that is standalone, so that later on our tool can be build only on this interpreter. Everything works fine but we must not alter the Setup file so we are looking to find another way to include the modules needed.